# adding a href in ajax while using codeigniter and getting data from curl

Tags: php, ajax, curl, codeigniter-3, href

I want to add a link inside AJAX and needs a `html.tpl[i]['nip']` in a tag because I want to display another view that required data with the chosen nip.

This is for PHP language in framework CodeIgniter and getting data from CURL. I have tried different ways to solve it but still, display wrong when I add link function, the AJAX is not working (not display the data).

I expect the output is when the link of detail is click the will display the view of data required with the nip. I expect the output is the table working properly and can choosing the link and can display the view that the data is required with the nip.

What's going wrong?

```
+"<td><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/detail/');?>' >detail</a></td>"
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('Admin/piljur');?>",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      var data = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < html.tpl.length; i++) {
        data += "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>" + "<td>" + html.tpl[i]['nip'] + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<td><a href='<?php echo site_url('admin/detail/'//i want to adding the value (html.tpl[i]['nip']);?>' >detail</a></td>" + "</tr>";
      }
      $("#datatabel").append(data);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Is it possible to include the URL string with the data returned from `Admin/piljur`? Then you could write something like `<a href='" + html.tpl[i]['nipUrl'] + "' >detail</a>`.

Comment: yes... it is possible on the view that doesn't have an ajax.. (just a table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate the detail url into a variable to be used later after the ajax call success, like this :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let detail_url = '<?php echo site_url('admin/detail/'); ?>';
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('Admin/piljur');?>",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      var data = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < html.tpl.length; i++) {
        data += "<tr><td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>" + 
                "<td>" + html.tpl[i]['nip'] + "</td>" + 
                "<td><a href='" + detail_url + html.tpl[i]['nip'] + "' >detail</a></td></tr>";
      }
      $("#datatabel").append(data);
    }
  });
}
```